# C++ STL stack pop operation giving segmentation fault

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault, stack

I implemented a programming question from [this link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element/) in C++ but I am getting a segmentation fault in the `pop()` operation with my code. I am fairly new to C++ and can not seem to find the error myself.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>

using namespace std;

void printNge(int *arr);

int main() {
        int arr[] = {1,4,2,6,3,8,7,2,6};

        printNge(arr);

        return 0;
}

void printNge(int *arr) {
        stack<int> st;

        st.push(arr[0]);

        for(int i=1; i<9;i++) {
                while((st.top() < arr[i]) && (!st.empty())) {
                        cout << "Element is:" << st.top() << "  NGE is:" << arr[i] << endl;
                        cout << "Removing element: " << st.top() << endl;
                        st.pop();
                }
                cout << "Pushing element: " << arr[i] << endl;
                st.push(arr[i]);
        }
        while(!st.empty()) {
                cout << "Element is:" << st.top() << "  NGE is:" << -1 << endl;
                st.pop();
        }

}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Change the order of your check in the while loop. First check against stack being empty, then try taking top. ;-)

Comment: Yes, I'd also change that order: if the stack is empty makes no sense to check the top element

Comment: Probably the solution posted on that link using stack is not correct too. Analyze it !

Comment: Yeah! I just re-read my question and found the bug. Kindly post an answer and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`). Read carefully the documentation of [`std::stack`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/). Use the debugger (`gdb`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line

```
while((st.top() < arr[i]) && (!st.empty())) {
```

is what is causing the segfault. You have to check the stack for being empty before you try to access top, as caling `top` on empty stack invokes UB.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `pop_back` on an empty container is undefined. `std::stack` uses `std::deque` by default, see [std::deque::pop_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/pop_back):