# C++ stack with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a legacy program that uses a std::stack object to store some pointers.

```
std::stack<Widget*> widgetStack;
```

Now I want to change this to the new C++11 style

```
std::stack<std::unique_ptr<Widget>> widgetStack;
```

However in the code there is a function:

```
Widget* getLastWidget()
{
    if(!widgetStack.isEmpty())
    {
        return widgetStack.top();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm struggeling to get this function to work with the unique_ptr. The stack is the owner of the widgets and only when the stack is popped, should the Widget objects be destroyed. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: You do `.get()`

Comment: Then use `std::shared_ptr` or `std::weak_ptr`. You're using the wrong tool for the job...

Comment: [std::stack::top](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top) returns reference to object on the top. You can return `std::unique_ptr<Widget>&` in your function for example.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, but what does it return when the stack is empty?

Comment: If you're wanting to use the top object without removing it from the stack, then Passer By's suggestion to use `.get()` is a good choice.

Comment: @Frank According to cppreference, it invokes [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: @Frank It's UB according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26205712/5267751).

Comment: And... comments are neither for asking another questions nor for giving answers.

Comment: Is it a requirement that no `Widget` can outlive the stack object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the stack is the only owner of the pointer, then it is recommended to return the raw pointer, because raw pointer means "a pointer without ownership":

```
Widget* getLastWidget()
{
    if(!widgetStack.isEmpty())
    {
        return widgetStack.top().get();
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't like using raw pointers. You can simply change `std::unique_ptr` to `std::shared_ptr`, as suggested by @user202729

```
std::stack<std::shared_ptr<Widget>> widgetStack;

std::shared_ptr<Widget> getLastWidget()
{
    if(!widgetStack.isEmpty())
    {
        return widgetStack.top();
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

This way the pointers are still managed by the stack and you don't have to deal with them in raw form.

I suggested references in the comments, but it wouldn't be too good solution.  Returning reference makes it difficult to return indication of empty stack (like the `nullptr` in your example).

Comment: Note, however, that all `shared_ptr`s returned by the function then have shared ownership, meaning that even when the element is `pop`ed from the stack, it is not necessarily destroyed.

Comment: Indeed, I thought of this. But as @jotasi already points out this defeats my wish of having the stack own the objects.

Comment: @Frank If that is what you want, then this is not the right solution. But you have to be careful applying the other solution, returning a raw pointer, because there, the pointer will dangle, when the element is `pop`ed and you cannot really check whether that happened...

Comment: I see. In this case, raw pointers might be the most reasonable solution. But be careful, since the pointer on the stack can be popped while you are still using it as raw.

Comment: Incurring the overhead of `shared_ptr` is not worth the minor convenience over using `unique_ptr` unless you're sure you need shared ownership.